# Transpositions and Commutativity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Are disjoint transpositions commutative?

e.g. Does $(1~2)(4~6) = (4~6)(1~2)$?

Can't seem to find a clear answer to this question.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It depends whether they're disjoint

Comment: Iff they are disjoint.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that specific example you gave, yes, we have $(12)(46) = (46)(12)$. As written in comments, when transpositions are disjoint, they commute. But in general, the answer is no. For instance, take $(12)(13)$ and $(13)(12)$. Then you will see that they are not equal.

Comment: Thanks! Should have clarified I was working under the assumption that they're disjoint.

Comment: Yes, that's right. That one is answered in comments already.

Answer (score 1):

Transpositions commute if they are disjoint. In general, if you have two transpositions $(a~b)(c~d)$, where $a,~b,~c$, and $d$ are integers, then the transpositions commute if $\{a,b\}\cap\{c,d\}=0$. That is, if $a\neq c$, $a\neq d$, $b\neq c$, and $b \neq d$.

This is most easily understood when you consider what transpositions (or cycles in general) do: they permute an object. It's nice to think of the object in this case as just a list of numbers. In general, your transpositions work for a list of length $6$ or greater, but I will consider it of just length $6$ for this example. The list is then $[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]$. Applying $(1~2)(4~6)$, we first apply $(4~6)$ to get $[1,2,3,6,5,4]$, and then apply $(1~2)$ to get $[2,1,3,6,5,4]$. One can easily check that $(4~6)(1~2)$ produces the same result. If you play around with non-disjoint transpositions, you will notice that they do not commute.

Answer (score 0):

As you know the composition of functions is not necessarily commutative which implies that transpositions in general not being commutative.

For disjoint transpositions we have commutative property because they do not interfere with each other.